# OpenID information doesn't fit on accounts page and no hover option is provided

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, openid, profile-page, user-accounts

When logged in and on the Accounts page (e.g. clicking your username in the top bar), the page shows your details including the [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) string. Mine doesn't fit (or is presumably) underneath the "grey" area on the right. In case most are short, I'm just using a Google one so I would assume it isn't an edge case...

Naturally, I move my mouse over the top of it to see the value as a tooltip, etc., but none appears. Could such a feature be provided? The text is not fitting (and wrapping), and I guess it is a bug. But it doesn't have spaces, so no breaks, therefore not a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Developers/SO Team,

You've now fixed this request...whether you did because of this, I don't know...but there are timestamps!

```
Google (anemailaddress@gmail.com)
```

is much better (and neatly fits on the user page)! thanks!